# trouble with my setTime method

Tags: java

Hey guys so i need help with my setTime method. Basically this is the question in my assignment:

Consider a class Time that represents a time of day. It has attributes for the
hour and minute. The hour value ranges from 0 to 23, where the range 0 to
11 represents a time before noon. The minute value ranges from 0 to 59.
a. Write a default constructor that initializes the time to 0 hours, 0 minutes.
b. Write a private method isValid(hour, minute) that returns true if the
given hour and minute values are in the appropriate range.
c. Write a method setTime(hour, minute) that sets the time if the given
values are valid.

I need help with c, in my code you can see that i have the set time method but when i run my programs and enter the time it returns this instead of the numbers in entered:

```
Please enter the hour
3
Please enter the minute
23
The time is time.Time@4d546e25 time.Time@620b66cc
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

My code

```
   /*
```

* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package time;

/**
 *
 * @author 797286001
 */

public class Time {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

//default constructor

public static int hour;
public static int minute;


public Time(){
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;

}


 private static boolean isValid(int hour, int minute)
 //returns true if given hour & minute values are in range
 {
    if((hour >= 0 && hour <= 23) && (minute >= 0 && minute <=11))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
 }


public void setTime(int hour, int minute)
 //set time if given values are valid - 
{




}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // 
    Time.hour = 0;
  Time.hour = 0;
 Time hour = new Time();
 Time minute = new Time();




   System.out.println("The time is " + hour + " " + minute);


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTime` should not be reading anything from the keyboard; the parameters contain the values you need.

Comment: Okay so i removed they keboard stuff, and replaced it with `Time.hour = 0;` and `Time.minute = 0;` in my setTime void but i am still getting : The time is time.Time@45bab50a time.Time@64c3c749.

Comment: Not according to what it says in your question; if the code has changed, you need to show the *new code*.

Comment: Okay so i added the new code. Maybe i am not understanding the question c) is asking, it is telling me to **Write a method setTime(hour, minute) that sets the time if the given
values are valid.** Where do i put the given values?

Comment: This is getting tiresome; you claimed to have put in `Time.hour = 0; Time.minute = 0;`, but they are not there.

Comment: Sorry i added that now, also in `Time hour = new Time();
     Time minute = new Time();` hour and time are underlined with a yellow line, and it says Local variable hides a field.

Answer (score 0):

`Time hour = new Time();
Time minute = new Time();`

This creates two instances of your class named hour and minute. Then you try to print them out. The default toString() method prints out their location in memory.

Go ahead and create one instance of the class, then use that to call the methods you need to call. Also, your setTime method takes 2 parameters but doesn't use them.